# How can we await in dispatch for a particular value in redux action creator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Here I am setting a flag as true(initially flag=false) and I want that flag in another reducer and stop and untill the flag is true

**filterReduer.js**

```js
const filterReducer = (state = intialState, action) => {
  switch(action..type){
  case actionTypes.FILTER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        filtereData: action.data.messages,
        flag: true,
   
      };
      default state;
   }
  }
```

**OtherAction.js**

```js
export const mySolutions = (userId) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    let flag = await getState().filter.flag; // I am getting flag info from different reducer 
    let data = getState().filter.channelMetaData;
    console.log("data", data);
    dispatch(mySolutionStarts());
    }
    }
```

My flag is false unable to wait untill flag is true
My intenton is when flag is set true the api call and data is updated to state and where I can use the state info for further call but unable to wait
Timeout is not a good idea where flag vaue is updated based on api call
is there any different approcah ?

Answer (score 1):

First, in case you pasted your code here, you should change

```
switch(action..type){
    // ...
    filtereData: action.data.messages,
    // ...
}
```

to

```
switch(action.type){
    // ...
    filterData: action.data.messages,
    // ...
}
```

As for dispatching an action on successful API response: I have to assume a lot, but let's hope that you have an initial action with the API call. If so, you should simply dispatch the second action within the same function that dispatches the first. Something like:

```
const myAsyncAction = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: FIRST_ACTION }); // perhaps you want to set the flag here

    // async API call here

    if (apiRes.status === 200) { // if successful response
        dispatch({ type: SECOND_ACTION }) // set flag again
    }
}
```

As far as I know, you can dispatch as many different actions as you like in there. Don't forget to import the actions if needed.

Comment: But,How can you await in another action file with two dispatch action references ? How can I stop this  let flag = await getState().filter.flag; untill flag reaches true @Ryan

Comment: @AkhilRaghav, I'm not sure what you're trying to do in `OtherAction.js`. It looks like you are trying to do something with `channelMetaData` after setting it via another action. Also, I can't see where you're calling this function `mySolutions()`. Are you calling it anywhere? You could just run this code right after you set the `flag` to true, in the same function.

This line doesn't achieve anything: `let flag = await getState().filter.flag;`

Comment: so here [let flag=await getState().filter.flag]; this flag detail is asynchronous how will it await for true it will move next line.and mySolutions I will be calling in component level so my intention is to wait untill flag becomes true ,its not working

Comment: @AkhilRaghav, are you trying to "listen" for the flag change (wait passively in this action for it to change)? If so, that won't work. I would expect some errors from the aforementioned line. Please update your question to include the full scope (components, actions, etc.), so that I can try to help.